# Edit VM setting so he configurate like a 84-bit processor

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, 64-bit, esxi

How can I the virtual machine settings change from an ESXi5 64-bit machine so that I can configurate it like a 84-bit operation? I'll nothing change to my guest operation system!

> This virtual machine is configures for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.

Comment: I believe you'd mean as a 32 bit or x86 operation.

Comment: 84 bit operation? Did you mean 64 bit?

Comment: This question is clearer if you look at the screenshot that was included in the original revision.  I tried to revise the question to add the screenshot back, but my edit was rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help says, you need to enable virtualisation in the BIOS. Restart your machine, enter the BIOS and look for a setting along the lines of Intel Virtualisation / Intel VT(-x) - Enable this and you should be able to continue.